# event listeners on load by ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I upload to the page  elements by ajax and some of them have children with class "evented". I need to add class to parent  on child load. I tried this

```
$(document).on('load','.evented',function(){         
    $('.evented').parent().closest('td').addClass('td_class');
});
```

But as expected it doesn't work because td doesn't have "load" event. I can execute this code like a part of ajax response but in this case I will have duplicate event listeners and I still need same code for elements that exist when document is ready.

Comment: So do you want a way to add the class "evented" or an event to the elements you are creating?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using load() method to load the contents, In that case you have to make use of the success handler of the load method to do this.

```
$(el).load(url, function(){
    $(this).find('.evented').closest('td').addClass('td_class');
})
```

---

If you are not using load() method, instead other ajax methods like $.ajax()/$.get() etc then after you add the contents to your page you will have to do this like

```
$.ajax(...).done(function(result){
    $(el).html(result).find('.evented').closest('td').addClass('td_class');
})
```